# how to compress the saved image in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, image, image-size

I have app in which i capture the image it works fine but i want to reduce the size of the image i searched from net i found some code which is here

This is my code working fine when image captured

```
NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

I want to reduce the size of picked image i got the following code but i am did not getting it use like it use newSize but where it is using the original image to compress

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: what you want ?? save that image with new size in your Phone Library??

Comment: Why don't you search before asking ? There are already many answers.

Comment: @ParasJoshi yes i want to save the captured image with compress size in documents folder of app

Comment: i post the answer try it out...

Comment: @user2240329 see my answer and save that new Image and check the photo album , you can see this new image with new size..

Comment: @user2240329 Check this [Documentation](https://gist.github.com/vksaini13/6051916)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is....

```
NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 CGSize sizeCropped = CGSizeMake(602, 450);//you can adjust any size here...

 pickedImage = [yourclassname imageWithImage:pickedImage scaledToSize:sizeCropped];//call below function...




+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
 }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy coding!!!!!

Comment: it does not compress size it shows 463KB i want it to reduce upto 100 KB

Comment: what size you have given to image , tell me... CGSize sizeCropped = CGSizeMake(602, 450);, whati s cropped size?

Comment: same as given by you i have given same size

Comment: first tell me which size you get of your pickedimage?what is the original size???

Comment: no no my friend, what is the height and width of your original image?give me width and height of pickedImage.

Comment: i get this image by capturing cam from ipad device

Comment: when i check the dimentions of this save image it shows 640 480 –

Comment: ok ,now give size 300(width) and 300(height).CGSize sizeCropped = CGSizeMake(300, 300);, then check how much space your image occupies?

Comment: but pic gets blurry when i compress this

Comment: actually , it depends upon the original image, if original image is blurry or of less resolution then the comressed image will get blurry.Just try to compress the image who has high resolution(like 1500 * 1200) or any.then see that image gets blurry or not
!!

Answer (score 0):

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize ); 
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

you can call this function where you want the compressed image using these lines of code.

```
    CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(210.0,210.0);
    UIImage *compImage=[mainclass imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:firstSize];
```

Comment: where to call this method

Comment: below this line UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

Comment: it shows size 463 KB no any effect

Comment: you can change first size variable accordingly eg.CGSize firstSize = CGSizeMake(20.0,20.0);

Comment: when i check the dimentions of this save image it shows 640 480

Comment: how can it be 640 *480 when you are passing 20 *20?

Comment: in main class i have to give the name of the class in which i write this method

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save that new Image with new size then after your code add that image in library with bellow line..

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

**EX:**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: just for your information i not post duplicate answer i have blog and i also post this type of answer before check it out

Comment: @TheTiger see this link http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/05/save-image-in-library-with-only-in-one.html

Comment: So you mean there is no other answer about UIImage resizing ?

Comment: this is not for resize the UIImage but he want to save that new image with this new size check it out comment on Question.. Please :)

Comment: Ha ha ha Nice joke. Please explain what are you doing in your answer if this is not about resizing.

Comment: Wooooo You did it ....

Comment: @ParasJoshi did you check the ankityadav answer there is not much different between your answer i tried that but not working

Comment: @user2240329 - There is a difference ankit didn't write `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` magical line :)

Comment: @user2240329 ankit's answer scale the image and here i saved the image ... thats one line is important .. i think about that you want to save that image so i post this answer.. :)